# Let $X$ be a TVS and let $f$ be a linear functional on $X$. If $f$ is continuous, how to show $f$ is bounded in some neighborhood of $0$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space and let $f$ be a linear functional on $X$. If $f$ is continuous, how to show $f$ is bounded in some neighborhood of $0$?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: See Theorem 1.18 of Rudin's Functional Analysis

Comment: @K.Power Yes I have read it but is that possible for $f$ bounded in some neighborhood of 0 with f=0?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but if $f=0$ on $X$ then $f$ is bounded in every neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: @K.Power True! But I am thinking is there a easier and more direct way to show it without using (c) in theorem 1.18 of Rudin's Functional Analysis.

Comment: Yes, Henno Brandsma' answer gives it you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume $f \neq 0$. Or else any neighbourhood of $0$ will do.

$O = f^{-1}[(-1,1)]$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ by continuity of $f$ (and $f(0) = 0$ of course). And clearly $f$ is bounded on $O$.

Comment: What if $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{F}$? How to set our set $O$?